# HTML lang attribute does not work in mPDF

Tags: php, mpdf

I'm currently working on making the correct version of language dependent glyphs show up in their respective PDF files... From what I understand after reading through the mPDF documentation is that all I need to do is to set the the html lang value like below and to set **autoScriptToLang** and **autoLangToFont** to **true**

Example html where I want the Japanese version of the characters:

```
<html lang="ja">
<body>
Sample language-dependent glyphs: 直今令角雇
</body>
</html>
```

And yet it doesn't seem to reflect on the PDF file that is generated.

Here's the settings I'm passing over to Mpdf\Mpdf

```
$settings = [
        'autoLangToFont' => true,
        'autoScriptToLang' => true,
        'format' => 'A4',
        'margin_left' => 10,
        'margin_right' => 10,
        'margin_top' => 10,
        'margin_bottom' => 20,
        'margin_header' => 0,
        'margin_footer' => 5,
        'tempDir' => '/tmp/',
        'default_font' => 'frutiger'
 ];
```

I tried displaying the HTML I'm passing over to mPDF and it works there, so I believe my issue is that I'm missing a setting to allow mPDF to display the Japanese versions of those characters.

Comment: That's not even remotely enough of shared code. Show more.

Comment: I edited it for more information now.

Comment: And what is the problem exactly? The code you provided renders japanese characters (i think) correctly.